# Twitter API returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, twitter, signature

I am trying to search tweets by location in Unity3D by using Twitter API.
I have problem with creating the authentication signature. When I try to put the request from Postman and use the generated header it also works in Unity but when I try to create the signature within Unity by myself I always get the *401 Unauthorized error* from server. So I am sure that the tokens and secrets work, the only problem is the signature.
Here is how I created the signature:

```
private string CreateSignature(string url)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.Append("POST&");
    stringBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(url));
    stringBuilder.Append("&");

    var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"oauth_consumer_key", _mOauthConsumerKey},
        {"oauth_nonce", _mNonce},
        {"oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"},
        {"oauth_timestamp", _mTimeStamp},
        {"oauth_token", _mOauthToken},
        {"oauth_version", "1.0"}
    };

    foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
    {
        stringBuilder.Append(Uri.EscapeDataString(string.Format("{0}={1}&", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value)));
    }

    var signatureBaseString = stringBuilder.ToString().Substring(0, stringBuilder.Length - 3);

    var signatureKey = Uri.EscapeDataString(_mOauthConsumerSecret) + "&" +
        Uri.EscapeDataString(_mOauthTokenSecret);

    var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(
            ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureKey));


    var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacsha1.ComputeHash(
            ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureBaseString)));

    return signatureString;
}
```

And here how I create the nonce and timestamp:

```
_mNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(
    DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

var timeSpan = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var stamp = ((long)(DateTime.UtcNow - timeSpan).TotalSeconds);
_mTimeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(stamp).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pro tip: timestamp in one line: `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`. Can you use Fiddler to inspect the difference between what your code is sending and Postman?

Comment: @Crowcoder ToUnixTimeSeconds was not supported in .NET 3.5. Isn't Fiddler the same as Postman?

Comment: Fiddler has a different use case though they overlap. Fiddler will trace the network and show you what your request initiated from c# is doing, Postman can't do that, it only traces requests sent through itself.

Comment: I could not get any valuable information from Fiddler as well

Comment: You should be able to look at the HTTP request and look at Postman's HttpRequest and see what is different

Comment: I can see the headers but could not find the authentication header

Comment: Well there you go. You have shown *how* you create the auth header but you don't show how it is assigned to the request.

Comment: But I also get "No Authorization Header is present." for Postman request.